# cl.exe failed with exit status 2 while installing PyCrypto

Tags: windows, python-3.x, anaconda, pycrypto

I was trying to install PyCrypto using PIP command

pip install pycrypto

I encountered  error as,

```
error: command 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio\\2017\\BuildTools\\VC\\Tools\\MSVC\\14.15.26726\\bin\\HostX86\\x64\\cl.exe' failed with exit status 2
```

Please help me if anyone knows how to resolve this issue.

Comment: Do you have the build tools installed and are they on your PATH?

Comment: Yes, I have installed Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 @spikespaz

Comment: Did you tried with conda instead of pip ?

Comment: Yes I tried conda instead of pip...Its showing '# All requested packages already installed.' @JR Utily

Answer (score 0):

Searching about cli.exe and python lead me to https://github.com/explosion/spaCy/issues/2507

**TLDR:**

Choose one

- use conda instead of pip
- downgrade your python to 3.6 or lower
- download an already compiled pycrypto and install it manually